# extra spaces between buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have implemented a code to make GUI using Tkinter and I'm new in this. The problem which I'm facing is that there is lots of spacing between two buttons in column 3 ( select object and play button).

I want to know that why this is happening.

[image]

my code is here:

```html
from tkinter import Tk, Text, BOTH, W, N, E, S
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("Nav Track app")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)

        lbl = Label(self, text="Keep your eyes on screen")
        lbl.grid(sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)

        area = Text(self)
        area.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=5,
                  padx=8, sticky=E + W + S + N)

        abtn = Button(self, text="Start Camera")
        abtn.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=4)

        cbtn = Button(self, text="Select Object")
        cbtn.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=4, pady=4)

        dbtn = Button(self, text="Play")
        dbtn.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=4, pady=4)


        hbtn = Button(self, text="Help")
        hbtn.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5)

        obtn = Button(self, text="Exit")
        obtn.grid(row=7, column=3)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("500x450+300+500")
    app = Example()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: try this one `self.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)`